# Desktop shortcut doesn't work for script but script work fine

Tags: bash, scripts, music, shortcuts

```
#!/bin/bash/
ls -1 *.mp3 > playlist.m3u
for (( ; ; )) do mplayer -playlist playlist.m3u; sleep 0.1; done
```

This is the script and it works !

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Play
Comment=Play music
Exec=bash /home/awesome/Desktop/test/play.sh
Icon=
Terminal=true
GenericName=Player
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the bash at the beginning of the exec command? Have you made it executable with chmod?

Comment: chmod 755 play.sh
chmod +x play.sh
Yes i made.

Comment: And desktop shortcut run but make error empty playlist,, but script make playlist :/

Comment: that is because of absolute paths...

Comment: Yes i tried but without bash script didnt work.

Comment: how can i find absolute paths ?

Comment: See my new answer, that should fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this working use the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Play
Comment=Play music
Exec=bash /home/awesome/Desktop/test/play.sh
Path=/home/awesome/Desktop/test/
Icon=
Terminal=true
GenericName=Player
```

Comment: There was an error launching the application

Comment: sorry, slight mistake